# Getting error "too many characters in character literal" and "type or namespace 'where' could not be forund"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Okay, i tried many things but can't get this through
These are the lines which are giving an error

```
    string AcceptFriendQuery ="Update Freinds set Status=1
    where MyId='"+SenderFriendId+"'AND FriendId=**'"+MyId+"'";
```

and

```
string RejectFriendQuery = "Update Friends set Status=2 
    where MyId='" + SenderFriendId + "' AND FriendId='" + MyID + " ' ";
```

Following are the errors:

> Too many characters in character literal The type or namespace name
>   'where' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?) The type or namespace name 'AND' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The line break breaks your string literal. Add a backwards slash after the lines if you want to include the line break in your string

Comment: i was trying to add bold tags sorry m a newbie

Comment: What is `SenderFriendId` and `MyId`?

Comment: @user2224966 place that query in a single line. don't break that query into two lines.

Comment: @user2224966 also it is better to use parameterized query than a string concatenated with plus(+) sign to avoid sql injection attacks .

Comment: @user2224966  see this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: @FrebinFrancis: That is a lot of affection ;)

Answer (score 4):

I tried putting your code on one line, and it works fine if both `SenderFriendId` and `MyId` are integers.

```
int SenderFriendId = 0;
int MyId = 0;

string AcceptFriendQuery ="Update Freinds set Status=1 where MyId='"+SenderFriendId+"' AND FriendId=**'"+MyId+"'";
```

**I would strongly recommend to use SQL parameters instead. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).**

Then your SQL would look like (depending on your database platform):

```
string AcceptFriendQuery ="Update Freinds set Status=1 where MyId=@myId AND FriendId=@friendId";
```

Comment: good job man. you done it the right way. one vote for that. :)

Comment: Recommendation is absolutely relevant! It is not only clearly readable but also more secure

Comment: @user2224966: Need more help? If not, please accept the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's C# why don't you use escaped string?

```
  string AcceptFriendQuery = @"Update Friends set Status=1
    where MyId='"+SenderFriendId+"'AND FriendId='"+MyId+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Write on one line:

```
 string AcceptFriendQuery ="Update Freinds set Status=1 where MyId='"+SenderFriendId+"'AND FriendId='"+MyId+"'";
```

or in two lines concatenating:

```
string AcceptFriendQuery ="Update Freinds set Status=1"
+ "where MyId='"+SenderFriendId+"'AND FriendId='"+MyId+"'";
```

Moreover:

- variables should start with lowercase.
- probably a typo: Update *Freinds*